# How do I calculate the percentage of a count function?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, bids

I am trying to take the percentage of a count function so to create a MS BIDS report resembling this excel file:
[Excel Close Rate Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ol0.png)

The unique identifier for the opportunities is the field "opportunityid", so I am using COUNT(Fields!opportunityid.Value) to determine the number of cases in each stage. I want to write an expression that will return the percentage of cases in each stage per creation month. Which can be seen in the above excel screenshot.

[This is my current MS BIDS report when i preview it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJpmG.png)

To be more specific, I want to have the percentage of "Active" and "New" opportunities in January to represent 67%  and 33% respectively. 67% comes from 4/6. The 4 comes from the active opportunities out of the 6 opportunities created in January.  Likewise, the 33% comes from the 2 new opportunities out of the 6 that were created in January.

There are more stage names than Active and New. Other options include New, Warm, Hot, Implementation, Active, Hibernate or Canceled. This is relevant to mention because I have tried to create an expression that counts based on the number of opportunities with a specific stage name, but have been unsuccessful.

Currently the expression I am using to calculate the percentage is:

=COUNT(Fields!new_rptstage.Value)/SUM(COUNT(Fields!opportunityid.Value),"GroupbyStageName")

Based on this expression, I am only able to get 1/1 or 100% for each of the stage names. I have tried a bunch of variations of the above expression by changing the scope, but have been unsuccessful in getting the desired results. Can someone explain how to correct this?

SAMPLE DATA:

[image]

In the sample data, I want the expression to be in the percentage column. The percentage should be the # of cases in a particular stage for the total cases that month. So looking at the above picture:

Active  February 54   54/168    [have 54/168 display as a percentage]

Warm    February 8    8/168
etc.

EDIT:

These are the expressions that may help show the underlying data in the chart. 
[image]

The creation month expression is 
    =Fields!MonthCreated.Value &  " " & year(Fields!createdon.Value)
The percent expression is listed above.

Comment: Please add sample data in the question itself, and explain why it should produce the results of 67% / 33%.

Comment: @TabAlleman okay! Please see the updated question for new data and a clarified explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use the COUNT() function.   COUNT(*) returns a count of the number of rows that have a value.   It doesn't return the actual value.

Since you've only showed a screen shot of your report, I don't know how your underlying data columns relate to it, but what you want to do for your `Percent` column expression is this:

```
This is psuedo code because I don't know your dataset field names:
CaseCount.Value / SUM(CaseCount.Value)
```

EDIT:   Now that I better understand how your data relates to your report, I think the only change you need to make to your existing formula is casting it to a decimal type.   It's probably rounding all fractions up to 1.

Try this for the expression in your percentage column:

```
=CDbl(COUNT(Fields!new_rptstage.Value))/CDbl(SUM(COUNT(Fields!opportunityid.Value),"GroupbyStageName"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure the best way to capture all the underlying data. The case count column is expressed by =COUNT(Fields!opportunityid.Value) because the CRM has no way of capturing the relative amount of cases opened in a certain month.

Comment: Updated to show the field names utilized in the table along with the expression for the Creation Month column

Comment: Unfortunately that expression still returns 1's instead of a decimal; Likewise, I tried with "CDbl" as "CDec" instead and that returns 1's also.

Comment: Maybe that's what happens when you do an aggregation on top of an aggregation (ie:   SUM(COUNT()).  I would approach this by trying to have the dataset output the counts, so that you don't have to use COUNT() in the SSRS, and you can just use the first expression in my answer above.

Comment: marking this as the answer. That code was correct, but i had to change the denominator to the parent group name to capture the sum of all the cases. Thank you!!